# How to loop over keys in JSON data

Tags: python, api, loops

I have a large list of gps coordinates and a large list of dates, and I trying to pull data using an API that gives json data that looks like this for one pair of gps coordinates:

```
{
 "features": [
  {
   "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
     74.11311,
     30.71151,
     191.24
    ],
    "type": "Point"
   },
   "properties": {
    "parameter": {
     "T2MWET": {
      "20150101": -3.44,
      "20150102": -0.85
     }
    }
   },
   "type": "Feature"
  }
 ],
```

where the data I care about is in the keys "20150101" and "20150102". These are dates and eventually I will have hundreds of these (each day in a year).

What I have come up with is this (I will read in gps coordinates and a list of dates):

```
gps_pairs = [('30.71152', '74.11307'), ('60.71393', '74.11334')]

dates = ['20150101', '20150102']

wbt2 = []

for p in gps_pairs:
  url_a = "https://power.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/v1/DataAccess.py?&request=execute&identifier=SinglePoint&parameters=T2MWET&startDate=20150101&endDate=20150102&userCommunity=AG&tempAverage=DAILY&outputList=CSV&"
  url = url_a + "lat="+ p[0] + "&lon=" + p[1]
  data_json = requests.get(url).json()
  if 'error' not in data_json:
    for d in dates:
          wbt2.append([data_json['features'][0] ['geometry']['coordinates'],
                     data_json['features'][0] ['properties']['parameter']['T2MWET'][d],])

dataset = pd.DataFrame(wbt2)
dataset
```

I am largely ok with this, except the output is

```
                0                      1
0   [74.11308, 30.71153, 191.24]    -3.44
1   [74.11308, 30.71153, 191.24]    -0.85
2   [74.11335, 60.71394, 58.7]      -26.20
3   [74.11335, 60.71394, 58.7]      -33.39
```

But I want this:

```
    0                                1        2
0   [74.11308, 30.71153, 191.24]     -3.44   -0.85
1   [74.11335, 60.71394, 58.7]      -26.20  -33.39
```

Looks like my loop over dates is not in the right place?

I am also not sure how long this will take to run when I have a thousand+ GPS coordinates and 365 dates, and if there are more efficient ways. (I am only a month or so into using Python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will get you all the values under `T2MWET`, regardless of date.

```py
values = list(data_json['features'][0] ['properties']['parameter']['T2MWET'].values())
```

So, if I'm following what you want to happen:

```
for p in gps_pairs:
  url_a = "https://power.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/v1/DataAccess.py?&request=execute&identifier=SinglePoint&parameters=T2MWET&startDate=20150101&endDate=20150102&userCommunity=AG&tempAverage=DAILY&outputList=CSV&"
  url = url_a + "lat="+ p[0] + "&lon=" + p[1]
  data_json = requests.get(url).json()
  if 'error' not in data_json:
    wbt2.append([data_json['features'][0] ['geometry']['coordinates'],
                list(data_json['features'][0] ['properties']['parameter']['T2MWET'].values())])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works. I then did a final pandas manipulation to get it excatly as I need

Comment: @Dee glad to hear it. Accept the answer and upvote it works for you!

Comment: It would be nice to accept @Dee answer by ticking it, since he helped you with your question.

Comment: Ah sorry, did it now. Doesn't show mu upvate though since I'm new